# how to hide default keyboard of windows,android and ios tab in xamarin app

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows, xamarin.forms

I have developed a xamarin form app and, i want to hide default keyboard in all three platform.
**1.** For windows tabs they have own service to stop screen keyboard.After stop that windows services then on click non textbox then screen keyboard is not displaying.
**2.** But For android and iOS they don't have service for disable screen keyboard, But i don't want appear screen keyboard on click on textbox or something of both (Droid and iOS).I want to display my costume keyboard on xamarin form from program.

->is it possible to hide default keybord of  both (Droid and iOS).

**If yes then**
         How Programmatic or device setting ?
**If No then**
Why? or any other source to hide or not?

Thanks & Regards,
Prabhhu Nath Singh

Answer (score 0):

set readonly property of textbox. and invoke your custom keyboard from the OnClick handler method.

Comment: Aswin Thank you for your reply :)
if i make textbox is readonly, then definitely that screen keyboard will not display, but this is not a good idea, because my costume keyboard will work like same as default screen keyboard on that editable textbox.
please give me some other point to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Froms you are able to use only common features what available in all 3 platforms. Only windows platform features you can't access in other two.In Android we have Toast massage feature but other 2 platform don't have. That's why Toast is also not works in Xamarin.Froms.